# Android (Kotlin) Why does this function exit before getting a JSON response?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley

I created a simple function to get content of url as json.

But as you see here the function exits before getting the result. Image link:
https://i.ibb.co/jTzyz6r/kotlingetjson1.png

```
fun JsonGet(url: String): String {
    d("info", "JsonGet() ---> Started ")
    var Result = ""
    var queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext())
    var req = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener {
                response ->
            d("info", "JsonGet() : success ")
            d("info",  "Response is= "+response)
            Result = response.toString()
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            d("warning", "JsonGet() : error")
        }
    )
    queue.add(req)

    d("info", "Result before fun exit=" + Result)
    d("info", "--> JsonGet() : finished ")
    return Result
}
```

Log:

```
D/info: JsonGet() ---> Started 
D/info: Result before fun exit=
D/info: JsonGet() : finished 
D/info: JsonGet() : success 
D/info: Response is= {"Users":[{"Username":"Jack","Country":"France"}]}
```

the result is needed for my app to decide what's next. Must wait for the result.
I searched in the documentation but didn't find something about "waiting" for response.

(By the way, I don't care about user experience because this app is private, so if the solution makes the app frozen it is ok.)

Comment: "Must wait for the result" -- no, you need to provide a listener or callback to be able to react to the response. Or, you could use coroutines and [use `suspendCoroutine()` to convert your callback-based API into a coroutine](https://jacquessmuts.github.io/post/callback_hell/). Or, you could switch to a coroutines-ready REST library, such as Retrofit.

Comment: have a look at this link if you want to know how to get data from an async operatoin : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare and  @ a_local_nobody  for the quick reply, I will try these.